# Mean center the dependent variable for within-subject comparison?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am doing a mixed model using the different subjects as a random effect. For avoiding any between-subject comparison I am mean-centering the different explanatory variables. Is it correct to also mean-center the dependent variable? I do not find any reason not to do it, but I have not find any paper doing it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to center the dependent variable. All this will achieve is to change the estimate for the global intercept (fixed effect). All the other estimates will remain unchanged. If you do center it, then you will need to add the value of the mean to get predictions on the original scale.

For example:

```
require(lme4)
m0 <- lmer(weight ~ Time * Diet + (1 + Time | Chick), data=ChickWeight, REML=F)
summary(m0)

m1 <- lmer(weight - mean(ChickWeight$weight) ~ Time * Diet + (1 + Time | Chick), data=ChickWeight, REML=F)
summary(m1)

Formula: weight ~ Time * Diet + (1 + Time | Chick)
   Data: ChickWeight

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 Chick    (Intercept) 103.61   10.179        
          Time         10.01    3.165   -0.99
 Residual             163.36   12.781        
Number of obs: 578, groups:  Chick, 50

Fixed effects:
           Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  33.6541     2.8023  12.009
Time          6.2799     0.7303   8.598
Diet2        -5.0205     4.8072  -1.044
Diet3       -15.4038     4.8072  -3.204
Diet4        -1.7475     4.8145  -0.363
Time:Diet2    2.3293     1.2508   1.862
Time:Diet3    5.1430     1.2508   4.112
Time:Diet4    3.2528     1.2515   2.599

Formula: weight - mean(ChickWeight$weight) ~ Time * Diet + (1 + Time | Chick)
   Data: ChickWeight

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 Chick    (Intercept) 103.61   10.179        
          Time         10.01    3.165   -0.99
 Residual             163.36   12.781        
Number of obs: 578, groups:  Chick, 50

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) -88.1642     2.8023 -31.461
Time          6.2799     0.7304   8.598
Diet2        -5.0205     4.8072  -1.044
Diet3       -15.4038     4.8072  -3.204
Diet4        -1.7475     4.8145  -0.363
Time:Diet2    2.3293     1.2508   1.862
Time:Diet3    5.1430     1.2508   4.112
Time:Diet4    3.2528     1.2515   2.599
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case I will have different means as for each subject the center is different. In my case the estimates change.